# renaming file after upload from html form

Tags: php, html

This is the upload form

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="uploaded" id="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the php:

```
<?php

    $keys = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        $photoID .= $keys[rand(0, strlen($keys)-1)];
    } 

    //add a dot (.) to the randomly generated string so the ext can be applied to it later
    $photoID2 = $photoID.".jpg";

    //This assigns the subdirectory you want to save into... make sure it exists!
    $target = "uploads/";

    //This combines the directory, the random file name, and the extension
    $target = $target . $photoID2.$ext; 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        echo "The file has been uploaded as ".$photoID2.$ext;
    } else {
        echo "Error: upload did not work";
    }
?>
```

The problem I have is that i keep getting the error upload did not work... what am I doing wrong here ? it's really basic something that I am missing but i need to understand it because I can already do file uploads fine but want to understand how it works...

Comment: Make sure the target folder in $target exists and $target has suffient permissions (chmod)

Comment: Well, you have to look what the error actually is to fix it. How to do that? PHP writes down its error. Take a look into the log file (http servers error log) and you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**First:**
 make sure that there is a directory with the name `uploads` 
**second:**
Try to give the suitable permissions to the directory using chmod like

```
chmod -R 777 /path/to/the/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for renaming a uploaded file

```
$name = $_FILES['Fixtures']['uploaded']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];
$target_path = "images/uploads/";
$extension = end(explode('.', $name));
$randomName = 'thumbnail_' . rand(123456, 1234567890) . '.' . $extension;
/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
  Result is "images/uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename($randomName);
$allowedImageTypes = array("image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/x-png", "image/gif");
if (in_array($type, $allowedImageTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path) or die("error in thumbnail upload!");
}
```

This will upload all the files with renaming the files

Comment: what is the ['Fixtures'] ? ... will give this a try and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry that fixtures in my model name you can use your model name in which your form is working

Answer (score 0):

Check the folder permissions of uploads/ if it's writeable for apache.

And try to set the [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) so `move_uploaded_file` can tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will settle with this solution, it makes more sense to me, the move_uploaded_files is the one that puts it in the directory and gives it the name.

```
<?php 

  //create random file name
    $keys = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

     for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)    
        {                         
      $key .=  $keys[rand(0, strlen($keys)-1)];      
      }

 //get the extension
  $ext = basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['type']);

 //choose destination, add filename and extension
   $target = "uploads/" .$key. "." . $ext; 


 //move the file to the des
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
  echo "The file has been uploaded";
  } 
  else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
  ?>
```